# in javascript, is there syntatic shortcut checking existence of each layer of embedded object?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

for example, the following code

```
  if( obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4 == 'constant' ) return;
```

needs to be rewritten as

```
  if( obj.attr1 
      && obj.attr1.attr2 
      && obj.attr1.attr2.attr3
      && obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4 == 'constant' ) return;
```

am I correct in that each layer needs to be tested individually, or is there a syntactic shortcut for this?

if this were a one-shot would not be a problem, but this construct permeates my code.

---

---

from answers, here is the solution I have in situ:

```
try{ if( obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4 != 'const' ) throw 'nada'; } catch(e){
    nonblockAlert( 'Relevant Message' );
    return;
};
```

this works since the error thrown for attr's non-existence is caught with the local throw().  the problem is the syntax does not fit in will with a normal if then else control.

Comment: That's basically the best way I know of.

Comment: @Mauvis - do you think there's any way to universally catch the particular error and let the statement fall through?

Comment: there is always `window.onerror` ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of code paths does your function expect to receive is it possible that the data in truly is (obj could be null? obj.foo could be null? obj.foo.bar could be null? etc.) I don't know about you but when I have a data structure or deep object like that the chances that each and every sub node could be null is rare and an indication that a redesign could help. Usually if you have a property in an object the rest of the "schema" should be well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have mentioned, but nobody has done, you can use try/catch:

```
try {
    if(obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4 == 'constant') return;
} catch(e) {}
```

It's not the best code ever, but it's the most concise, and easily readable. The best way of avoiding it would be not to have so deeply nested a tree of possibly-absent objects.

Comment: of the two approaches, the getProp() above and throw, I think throw is less cumbersome.  would be nice to combine to make syntactically nicer, but since it's impossible to defer evaluation of function args, stuck with catch and throw.  thanks.

Comment: as per comment above, do you think there any way to universally catch this particular error and let the statement fall through?

Comment: Take note that if you have to try catch something like that perhaps the problem is elsewhere? Ask yourself: "am I masking the real problem by attempting to ignore the error?" Is it truly the case that the deep nested object has a high likelihood that it is garbage? And if so perhaps a validation function is in order.

Answer (score 3):

there's no real shortcut.  You can write a helper function to do it for you, something that can condense to:

```
function getProp(obj){
    var i=0, l=arguments.length;
    while(i<l && (obj = obj[arguments[i++]]));
    return obj;
}
if( getProp(obj, 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4') == 'constant')
```

or you can do:

```
var tmp;
if((tmp = obj.attr1)
    && (tmp=tmp.attr2)
    && (tmp=tmp.attr3)
    && (tmp.attr4 == 'constant')) {
```

Comment: thanks - while getProp() works, somewhat cumbersome.  think will go with the ugly catch/throw below

Comment: **+1** for the second solution. That's quite elegant

Comment: @cc young - your code, you can do whatever, but I personally think defining this once and then having this if statement is far less cumbersome than putting a `try/catch` in every time.  Plus, your `try` would need to wrap the ___entire___ if clause, potentially spanning dozens or more lines.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question - though I've never had the problem myself. The best alternative I can think of is to write a helper function:

```
function get(chain, context) {
   var o = arguments.length == 2 ? context : window,
       c = chain.split('.');
   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
       if (!o) return null;
       o = o[c[i]];
   }
   return o;
}
```

If `obj` is global then you can do something like:

```
if (get('obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4') == 'constant') return;
```

Otherwise:

```
if (get('attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4', obj) == 'constant') return;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, there isn't, short of using `try/catch`. You could, though, write yourself a helper function (untested, but the concept is there):

```
function existsAndEquals(obj, layers, compare) {

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++)
        if (!(obj = obj[layers[i]]))
            return false;

    return obj == compare;

}

if (existsAndEquals(obj, ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4'], 'constant'))
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use call (or apply) to shift the context of a string evaluation
from the window to any object

```
function getThis(string){
    var N= string.split('.'), O= this[N.shift()];
    while(O && N.length) O= O[N.shift()];
    return O;
}


window.obj={
    attr1:{
        attr2:{
            attr3:{
                attr4: 'constant!'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**getThis('obj.attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4');**

/*  returned value: (String) '**constant!**' */

**getThis.call(obj, 'attr1.attr2.attr3.attr4');**

/*  returned value: (String) '**constant!**' */