# in javascript, are there built-in error codes? is it possible to trap an internal error? possible to continue?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

ok, I feel stupid asking this question, and forgive my poor research techniques, but...

using the example

```
  if( obj.attr1.attr2.attr3 == 'constant' ) return;
  else if( condition2 ) ...
```

if `obj.attr1` is undefined, the javascript engine throws an error.

1. what is the error that is thrown?  is it universally defined?
2. is is possible to globally trap *this* error?
3. if trapped, is it possible for the next line `condition2` to be executed?

to clarify: the error is raised because trying to get attribute of undefined.  is there any way to know that *this* is the error being raised?  is it in some table of standard javascript error messages?

and second, having trapped the error upstream, is it possible for program to flow uninterruptedly?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to trap this error with a try/catch block:

```
try{
    if( obj.attr1.attr2.attr3 == 'constant' ) {
        alert("test");
    }
}
catch(e)
{
    alert(e.Message);
}
```

The exception gives you the following:

```
description "'obj' is undefined"    String
message    "'obj' is undefined" String
name    "TypeError" String
number  -2146823279 Number
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is solved gracefully by *not blindly assuming that something is there*.

```
if( obj.attr1 && obj.attr1.attr2 && obj.attr1.attr2.attr3 == 'constant' )
```

Other than that, you can write a try/catch statement that catches the exception here, but using structured exception handling to direct the normal program flow is frowned upon and should be avoided.

Comment: in that regard, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302812/in-javascript-is-there-syntatic-shortcut-checking-existence-of-each-layer-of-emb, which addresses this specifically.  but still after the general know-how.